# How to compile a sketch using arduino-builder?

Tags: arduino-builder

How do you compile a sketch with a custom library path using [arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder)? The docs are a little light.

I have my source code organized like this:

```
lib
    SomeLib
        somelib.h
        somelib.cpp
src
    otherfile.h
    main.ino
```

I've installed Arduino 1.8.1 into /usr/share/arduino.

I'm trying to compile this for an Arduino Uno from my project root directory with:

```
arduino-builder -compile -hardware /usr/share/arduino/hardware -tools /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools -libraries lib -fqbn arduino:avr:uno -build-path .build src/main.ino
```

But it returns this error:

```
fork/exec {runtime.tools.ctags.path}/ctags: no such file or directory
```

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the path to the `tools-builder` folder, which is where `ctags` is. Try this:

```
arduino-builder \
  -compile \
  -hardware /usr/share/arduino/hardware \
  -tools /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools \
  -tools /usr/share/arduino/tools-builder \
  -libraries lib \
  -fqbn arduino:avr:uno \
  -build-path .build \
  src/main.ino
```

Comment: Is there a way to upload the compiled program to the Arduino using arduino-builder or some other cli tool?

Comment: This seems to do the trick for me:  `avrdude -V -F -C /etc/avrdude.conf -p atmega328p -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c arduino -b 115200 -U flash:w:sketch.hex`